# Somehow this code cannot run

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I recently trying to create a BMI calculator for iPhone. I started off with the layout and it is nearly done. Then when I try to run it, there is a SIGABRT in the file of AppDelegate.swift. I didn't alter anything in this file. Here is the code That I wrote:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var Height_txt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Weight_txt: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var Height_label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Weight_label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var Height_picker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Weight_picker: UIPickerView!

    var picker1Options = []
    var picker2Options = []

    @IBOutlet weak var Calc_button: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var Result_Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Description_Label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        picker1Options = ["ft","cm"]
        picker2Options = ["lbs","kg"]
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if (pickerView.tag == 1){
            return picker1Options.count
        }else{
            return picker2Options.count
        }
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if (pickerView.tag == 1){
            return "\(picker1Options[row])"
        }else{
            return "\(picker2Options[row])"
        }
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        Height_label = picker1Options[row] as! UILabel
        Weight_label = picker2Options[row] as! UILabel
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help according to this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try a full clean and rebuild? I need to do this sometimes to fix SIGABRT issues with Swift.

Comment: can you tell me how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Apple-Shift-K or use the menu: 'Product > Clean'.

Comment: Ok thanks, it is working now.